# Accessing TextView field from XML layout using inflation?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm relatively new to Android programming, and am having a problem with inflation.  I'm trying to create a simple activity that spits out a few descriptive fields from a previously selected ListView item.

I can access the source data from the ListView without any problems, but the subsequent activity to display the selected data isn't working.  Specifically, the following XML layout excerpt (in layout/info.xml) and corresponding code generates an activity that comes up OK, but doesn't display the string "XYZZY" as desired (as indicated above, the string is normally obtained dynamically from the ListView, but is simplified to a hard-coded string for this example).

What am I doing wrong?  Here's the XML excerpt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <!-- Info text -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/infoname"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    ...

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here's the java excerpt:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.info);

    LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
    View infoView = li.inflate(R.layout.info, null);

    TextView name = (TextView) infoView.findViewById(R.id.infoname);
    name.setText("XYZZY");

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by setting the contentView() you don't need to do the inflating yourself. The reason you are not seeing your text is that the inflated layout is not added to the view hierarchy.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.info);

    TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.infoname);
    name.setText("XYZZY");

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do setContentView(R.layout.info) and inflate in the same activity for the same layout, choose one of the approaches. For your example above there is the right code:

> ```
> @Override
> public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>
>     LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
>     View infoView = li.inflate(R.layout.info, null);
>
>     setContentView(infoView);
>     TextView name = (TextView) infoView.findViewById(R.id.infoname);
>     name.setText("XYZZY");
>
>     ...
>
> }
> ```